# SQL CASE with WHILE loop in not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I'm trying to include a WHILE loop inside a CASE statement but i am getting the following errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  iu.id AS 'number',
  iufv.v AS 'vnumber',
  iufv.timet AS 'time',
  iufv.loc AS 'loc',
  CASE WHEN iufv.timet <= GETDATE() THEN 
    DECLARE @checktime DATE
    SET @checktime = iufv.timet 
    WHILE iufv.timet <= GETDATE()
    BEGIN
      SET iufv.timet = DATEADD(DAY, 42, iufv.timet)
      PRINT @checktime
    End 
  GO
  ELSE 
    iufv.timet 
  END AS nexttime
FROM dbo.iu
       INNER JOIN dbo.iufv ON iu.active_ufv = iufv.gkey
       INNER JOIN dbo.sr ON iu.gkey = sr.applied_to_gkey
WHERE  iufv.ts = 'S4' AND iufv.loc = 'MBUL'
```

Expected output:

```
number vnumber time       loc  nexttime
300    v300300 28/12/2016 MBUL 22/03/2017
400    v400400 25/09/2016 MBUL 23/04/2017
500    v500500 18/12/2016 MBUL 23/04/2017
```

Logic of WHILE LOOP:

If the time is less than todays date add 42 days,

if its still less than todays date add another 42 days etc

until it is greater than todays date.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This is so not query syntax that it is really hard to figure out what you intend.

Comment: You can't use case for flow control, it's a statement designed to return a scalar value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT iu.id AS number, iufv.v AS vnumber, iufv.timet AS time,
       iufv.loc AS 'loc',
       dateadd(day,
               42 * ((datediff(day, iufv.timet, getdate()) / 42) + 1),
               iufx.timet
              ) as nexttime
FROM dbo.iu INNER JOIN
     dbo.iufv
     ON iu.active_ufv = iufv.gkey INNER JOIN
     dbo.sr
     ON iu.gkey = sr.applied_to_gkey
WHERE  iufv.ts = 'S4' AND iufv.loc = 'MBUL';
```

Comment: Works excellent! just missed a small comma on one of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Move `DECLARE @checktime DATE` above your query.  You can't declare variables *inside* a query statement.